# Confuse about django relationships

Tags: python, django, many-to-one

I'm developing a storage software and I got kind confuse with this relationship on Django.
The project's model has two classes:

Places:

```
class Places(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=11)
    ie = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=13)
    cep = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    cidade = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=54)
    bairro = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=54)
    num = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=54)
    rua = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=254)
    maintelefone = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
    sectelefone = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
    contactperson = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=254)
    site = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=254)
    razaosocial = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=254)
    fantasia = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=254)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.razaosocial
```

And Movementacao:

```
class Movimentacao(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    produto = models.ForeignKey(
        'Produto', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  # Automatizar
    qtd = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=1)
    numero_serie = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=154)
    tipoMov = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    nf = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=154)
    date_nf = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    origem = models.ForeignKey(
        'Places', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='origemovi', null=True)
    destino = models.ForeignKey(
        'Places', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='destinomovi', null=True)
    obs = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipoMov
```

The logic is that a `Place` can have one or more `Movimentacao`, and `Movimentacao` can just have one `Place` ( Many-to-One, I supose) ,but I expect that the `Place` got the id of the `Movimentacao` too, not just the Movimentacao get the id of the Place. How can I perform that?

Comment: You have that, with your `origem` and `destino` ForeignKeys and their respective related_names. What is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I mean that when I pass a list of Places I can't find the movementacao of this places like  the place with id 2 has the movement of id 6 and 7, I just can take that movement with id 6 has the place 2

Comment: Why not? Why can't you do `my_place.orgemovi_set.all()` to find all the Moviementacao that have that place as their origem?

Comment: That's what happen, code: `for i in lista_places:
                                                print(i.origemovi_set.all())` 
Error: `AttributeError: 'Places' object has no attribute 'origemovi_set'`

Comment: Sorry, you had `origemovi` as the related_name so it should be `i.origemovi.all()`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to do that, helped me a lot !